# log det on density matrix plus identity

Tags: quantum-mechanics, quantum-computation, quantum-information

A very naive question: given a pure quantum state $|\phi\rangle$, and the associated density matrix $\rho=|\phi\rangle\langle\phi|$, does there exist an efficient quantum operator/procedure that gives me $$\log\operatorname{det}(I+\rho)\quad?$$ Would I need any oracles?

Best,
Whoopy

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The oracle is just the [Mercator series](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mercator_series) for the log.

Since you have a normalized pure state,
$$
\operatorname {tr} \rho^2= \operatorname {tr} \rho= 1=\operatorname {tr} \rho^k,  
$$
for any *k*; so that, recalling [this](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jacobi%27s_formula#Corollary),
$$
\operatorname {log ~det }(I+\rho)=\operatorname {tr~log}(I+\rho)\\ = \operatorname {tr} \sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \frac{-(-)^n}{n} \rho^n= \sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \frac{(-)^{1+n}}{n}\operatorname{tr}  \rho^n =  \sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \frac{(-)^{n+1}}{n}=\log 2~~.
$$

Answer (score 2):

Assuming that the state space is finite dimesional there is a more pedestrian proof than the very nice once by Cosmas Zachos:

In a basis where $|\phi\rangle$ is the first basis vector the matrix $\rho=|\phi\rangle\langle\phi|$ is the projection matrix
$$
\rho=\begin{pmatrix}1&0&\dots&0\\0&0&\dots&0\\\vdots&\vdots&\ddots&\vdots\\0&0&\dots&0 \end{pmatrix}.
$$
Then clearly $\operatorname{det}(I+\rho)=2$ and $\log\operatorname{det}(I+\rho)=\log 2$.